# Handling webdav request and response in Play 2.0

Tags: java, playframework

Is there any work around for handling WEBDAV request and response in Play Framework 2.0?

I know that it is supporting in Play 1.0 (by adding * in router file)

Currently I am working on `Global.java` and using `oRequestRouted()`, but I am not able to send a response as xml back to client.

Thanks

Comment: @glidester I have added an answer to it.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Play framework 2.0 +`, it will not support `WebDav`. One approach is to convert existing application developed in Play framework to tomcat web application. Then you plug in your WebDAV support on top of that.

This is the only thing I know as far as providing support in Play framework.

However, I have not used this approach though.

Please let me know if anybody has done it similar to to my idea.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @UVM. I've managed to work out how to get Play 2.4.x to handle non-http-standard verbs (like PROPFIND). You were on the right lines with 'Globals.onRequestRouted()' but in 2.4 they do away with the Global object so you need to use https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaHttpRequestHandlers to code your own request->handler resolutions. I think it would be possible to then implement a WebDAV service in play but I've realised that I don't need WebDAV so I'll not be taking this any further.

Comment: @glidester, you are right, but I forgot to mention this point that it supports for SCALA. In my case I had to do with Java where it willl not. I could not use SCALA as  I do not not much about it,